# Word vba - change "," with "." and each "." with "," in any specified table (e.g. each table with 8 columns)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a total newbie in word vba and need to change some commas with full stops and do the same thing in opposite way in table with specified conditions. Can someone lend a hand? Any hint or reliable source of information would be nice.

This just sample code. I need to put restriction on find/replace method. For example only to tables with 8 columns.

```
Sub FormatMyTables()
    Dim oTb As Table
    For Each oTb In ActiveDocument.Tables
        oTb.Select
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "."
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.Text = ","
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
            Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        End With
    Next oTb
End Sub
```

Comment: you don't need any VBA for that. Just select the table and run `Find >> Replace` which is standard operation in MS-Word.

Comment: The document is quite big. I need to apply changes only in specified tables. Doing this manually each time will take many hours.

Comment: if so then do it in this way: Select table where you want to do replacement >> start Recording Macro >> do what you need using Find-Replace operation >> stop Recording. **As a result you will get macro you need.** Next, select the other table and run your macro. If you have 'specified tables' it will always require doing it partially manually.

Comment: I need a macro which will check each string in each cell of specified table. If the enouncter will be "." change with "," if "." change with ",". Your idea wont work because the data differs in almost each table. So recording one macro will not help. I want to change data in each table with 8 columns but different number of rows.

Comment: My idea will work for sure in three steps: 1. change `.` into anything like `{}`, 2. change `,` into `.`, 3. change `{}` into `,`. Three steps of one macro recording process and you have it done :)

Comment: and please remember: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Comment: Yes, I understand your solution. I tried with programming find/replace but I dont know how to put restriction for searching only in speacified tables.

Comment: you can always re-edit your question and add code there...

Comment: I know I need to change for each table but dont know. Alsto I am afraid that using find/replece here may be useless. I know that I can program it for certain number of steps but to restrict it to tables - is it possible? If not, then only comparing strings is left for me :(

Comment: I think you have 75% of your code. Copy `find-replace` section and do it in three steps as I mentioned in my comment above. What do you need more?

Comment: The problem is that as I used above code it provide changes also outside of tables. It changes every text.

Comment: give me few sec to provide final tips in the answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `Wrap parameter` to keep replacement only in selected area. I also added `if statement` to check if replacement will go only in table with 8 columns (according to your question). See some comments in the code below.

```
Sub FormatMyTables()
Dim oTb As Table

For Each oTb In ActiveDocument.Tables

    'check if table has 8 columns:
    If oTb.Columns.Count = 8 Then

    oTb.Select
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "."
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = ","

        'here I changed the wrap parameter:
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
                Wrap:=WdFindWrap.wdFindStop
    End With
    End If

Next oTb
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpfull. This _wrap_ is what I was looking for :]